# how to put a Video fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen

I'm triyng to put this video in fullscreen, it's workin on a desktop screen but not on a mobile screen

[image: mobile screen]

also my css :

```
.videoHomeContact {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the html code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy3GlrddZFI Maybe this help, there are alot of tutorials on youtube

Comment: @Fantantonio yes 
```
<Row>
        <video className="videoHomeContact" autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>

    
```

Comment: @WendyMontagnon desktop and mobile videos have to be different... depending on the type of video....if it is a portrait video..will be cropped on landscape screens and if it is a landscape video.. it will be cropped from sides depending on how you want...are you ok with cropping?

Comment: @himanshuBansal it's not a problem :)

Comment: @WendyMontagnon https://jsfiddle.net/x54p09eq/ Let me know if this works...added snipped in the answer too if you want to check....

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to open it on Fullscreen and to close it

```
      function openFullscreen(elem) { //Parameter is the video element
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is working for video backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

Is this workable?

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.v-header{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
}

.container{
  max-width:960px;
  padding-left:1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  min-height:100vh;
  min-width:100vw;
}

.header-overlay{
  height:100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  z-index:1;
  background:#225470;
  opacity:0.85;
}

.header-content{
  z-index:2;
}

.header-content h1{
  font-size:50px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.header-content p{
  font-size:1.5rem;
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:2rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoplay="" loop="">
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-content text-md-center">
      <h1>Welcome Everyone</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id temporibus perferendis necessitatibus numquam amet impedit explicabo? Debitis quasi ullam aperiam!</p>
      <a class="btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="section section-a">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section A</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section section-b">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section B</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add viewport metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And this styles to .videoHomeContact

```
height: 100vh;
width:100vw
```

vh stays for viewport height and vw for viewport width

Comment: The video is on the middle but don't take the full screen :(